# Каким образом получить только нужное значение?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Хочу сделать парсер информации с сайта. Для парсинга использую `simple html dom parser`.

На странице есть разметка вида:

```html
<table class='table_inner'>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/">Пункт 1</a></td>
   <td><a href="/">Значение пункта 1</a></td>
  </tr>
    
  <tr>
   <td>Пункт 2 </td>
   <td>Значение пункта 2</td>
  </tr>
    
  <tr>
   <td>Пункт 3</td>
   <td>Значение пункта 3</td>
  </tr>
    
  <tr>
   <td>Пункт 4</td>
   <td>Значение пункта 4</td>
  </tr>
    
  <tr>
   <td>Пункт 5</td>
   <td>Значение пункта 5</td>
  </tr>
  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Мне нужно получить только **Значение пункта 2**

Разметка всегда одинаковая.

```
$html = file_get_html('https://site.ru'); 
$a_links = $html->find('.table_inner');
```

Каким образом мне выбрать именно это значение? 
Буду благодарен за помощь.
P.S. нужно только значение(текст) этого пункта (Пункт 2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Каким образом мне выбрать именно это значение?

дак как-то так и выбрать:

```
$html->find(".table_inner tr",1)->find("td",1)->innertext;
```